# Openfire SSL certificat

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, openfire

I have an openfire server on centOS 7 and i want to install my wildcard certificate.

After importing certificate to keystore and tested it using

> keytool -list -v -keystore keystore -alias chat.example.com

Everything looks good, i get certificate provider, CN,OU, algorithms etc.

In my Web admin panel i set ServerName to chat.example.com
When i restart openfire i get:
Found RSA certificate that is not valid for the server domain
the log shows  me

> Check for certificate for 'chat.example.com' using algorithm RSA returned: false

Where i misconfigure my openfire server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the certificate alias

> ./keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore /root/cert.pfx

Then insert it in openfire

> ./keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /root/cert.pfx -destkeystore
>   /opt/openfire/resources/security/keystore -srcstoretype pkcs12
>   -deststoretype JKS -srcstorepass 'password' -deststorepass 'password' -srcalias 'alias' -destalias chat.example.com -destkeypass 'password'